# How to avoid dying weights/gradients in custom LSTM cell in tensorflow. What shall be ideal loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train a name generation LSTM network. I am not using pre-defined tensorflow cells (like tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell, etc). I have created LSTM cell myself. But the error is not reducing beyond a limit. It only decreases 30% from what it is initially (when random weights were used in forward propagation) and then it starts increasing. Also, the gradients and weights become very small after few thousand training steps.

I think the reason for non-convergence can be one of two: 
1. The design of tensorflow graph i have created  OR 
2. The loss function i used.

I am feeding one hot vectors of each character of the word for each time-step of the network. The code i have used for graph generation and loss function is as follows. Tx is the number of time steps in RNN, n_x,n_a,n_y are length of the input vectors, LSTM cell vector and output vector respectively. 
Will be great if someone can help me in identifying what i am doing wrong here.

```
n_x = vocab_size
n_y = vocab_size
n_a = 100
Tx = 50
Ty = Tx 

with open("trainingnames_file.txt") as f:
    examples = f.readlines()
examples = [x.lower().strip() for x in examples]
X0 = [[char_to_ix[x1] for x1 in list(x)] for x in examples]
X1 = np.array([np.concatenate([np.array(x), np.zeros([Tx-len(x)])]) for x in X0], dtype=np.int32).T
Y0 = [(x[1:] + [char_to_ix["\n"]]) for x in X0]
Y1 = np.array([np.concatenate([np.array(y), np.zeros([Ty-len(y)])]) for y in Y0], dtype=np.int32).T

m = len(X0)



Wf = tf.get_variable(name="Wf", shape = [n_a,(n_a+n_x)])
Wu = tf.get_variable(name="Wu", shape = [n_a,(n_a+n_x)])
Wc = tf.get_variable(name="Wc", shape = [n_a,(n_a+n_x)])
Wo = tf.get_variable(name="Wo", shape = [n_a,(n_a+n_x)])
Wy = tf.get_variable(name="Wy", shape = [n_y,n_a])
bf = tf.get_variable(name="bf", shape = [n_a,1])
bu = tf.get_variable(name="bu", shape = [n_a,1])
bc = tf.get_variable(name="bc", shape = [n_a,1])
bo = tf.get_variable(name="bo", shape = [n_a,1])
by = tf.get_variable(name="by", shape = [n_y,1])

X_input = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = [Tx,None])
Y_input = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = [Ty,None])

X = tf.one_hot(X_input, axis = 0, depth = n_x)
Y = tf.one_hot(Y_input, axis = 0, depth = n_y)
X.shape

a_prev = tf.zeros(shape = [n_a,m])
c_prev = tf.zeros(shape = [n_a,m])

a_all = []
c_all = []


for i in range(Tx):
    ac = tf.concat([a_prev,tf.squeeze(tf.slice(input_=X,begin=[0,i,0],size=[n_x,1,m]))], axis=0)
    ct = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(Wc,ac) + bc)
    tug = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Wu,ac) + bu)
    tfg = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Wf,ac) + bf)
    tog = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Wo,ac) + bo)
    c = tf.multiply(tug,ct) + tf.multiply(tfg,c_prev)
    a = tf.multiply(tog,tf.tanh(c))
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(Wy,a) + by, axis = 0)
    a_all.append(a)
    c_all.append(c)
    a_prev = a 
    c_prev = c
    y_ex = tf.expand_dims(y,axis=1)
    if i == 0:
        y_all = y_ex
    else:
        y_all = tf.concat([y_all,y_ex], axis=1)        



loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=Y,logits=y_all,dim=0))

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
train = opt.minimize(loss)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    o = sess.run(loss, feed_dict = {X_input:X1,Y_input:Y1})
    print(o.shape)
    print(o)
    sess.run(train, feed_dict = {X_input:X1,Y_input:Y1})
    o = sess.run(loss, feed_dict = {X_input:X1,Y_input:Y1})
    print(o)
```